# Django and microsecond discrepancy in DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models

I have a code that calculates a given datetime as follows

```
time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
```

I then use `time` to set a field in an `offer` object to be saved in the database. The `offer.time` is a `Offer` model instance; it is configured to be:

```
time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

It happens, however, that offer.time is updated when calling `offer.save()`. When setting `offer.time = time`, I get `2017-04-29 09:36:14.895581`. After calling `offer.save`, `offer.time` is `2017-04-29 09:36:14.895000`. Why isn't `save()` preserving the original time?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19716

Comment: @Grimmy This is unrelated. For the record, I am using MongoDB. I do see the point that maybe this is related to a precision problem.

Comment: ah. I guess maybe because BSON Date is a 64 bit integer storing milliseconds. Not sure if that has changed lately.

Comment: add mongodb tag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing
>   the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which
>   results in a representable date range of about 290 millions years into
>   the past and future.

This explains why `2017-04-29 09:36:14.895581` becomes `2017-04-29 09:36:14.895000`

`2017-04-29 09:36:14` will be stored as `1493458574000` leaving only 3 more decimals to store milliseconds. When adding milliseconds the value will be `1493458574895`. When this is read back into the `DateTimeField`, the value will be `2017-04-29 09:36:14.895000`.

Comment: I see this may indeed be a precision error. Still, I am not convinced with the explanation. 64 bits should have been enough to stored the data in question according to the explanation you have provided. Can you please clarify?

Comment: No problem. I will add more info.

Comment: You could make your own custom fields that stores a 64 bit integer as microseconds? I'm not sure how that would work in practice in mongodb.

Comment: The solution I had adopted was basically zeroing-out the microsecond part of the DateTimeField object I had. That level of information was irrelevant to my application.

Comment: At least we learned something. That is the most important part :)

Comment: I don't think I am confusing milliseconds with microseconds. In the Python documentation (remember DateTimeField maps to a datetime object in python), there exists a `microseconds` attribute, but not one for milliseconds. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html.
These are the components I have presented in my original question.